# Array defined in parent component cannot be sliced

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Must be a rookie mistake but here it is:

I have a parent component where i defined an array:

```
...
<object-list-grid
   v-bind:objects="objectsList"
></object-list-grid>
...
data() {
        return {
            ...
            objectsList: [],
            ...
        };
```

I pass this down to a child component (through another child component) as `objects`:

In middle child (object-list-grid):

```
<object-list
   :objects="objects"
></object-list>
...
props: ["objects"],
```

And finally in the last child:

`props: ["objects"],`

I want to create a subset of this array, but i fail to do this. I try to do it in `created()` of this last child; logs produce results i cannot understand:

```
console.log(this.objects);
console.log(this.objects.length);
console.log(this.objects.slice());
```

Produces the following result:

[image]

I noticed that in the log it shows as an **ob** object as opposed to an Array but as a read similar issues my impression was that its normal in Vue. Also it seems to me that the array has 17 elements.

Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Console logging is live. That's what the little blue `i` symbol is trying to indicate. At the point you log `this.objects` it is empty but the array is logged by reference. When you expand the array in the console it will show the current contents of that array, which may differ from the contents at the time it was logged. This is not related to Vue or reactivity, it is just how consoles log objects/arrays. Also try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.objects))`. As you already noted, the `__ob__` thing is perfectly normal for an array with Vue.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle! I was not aware of this feature of the console. Indeed this was the case and v-if-ing properly solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can tell @skirtle provided the best explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that at the time were `created` is executed the array is empty that's why `this.objects.length` and `this.objects.slice()` indicates that the array is empty.

The reason that `console.log(this.objects);` show the array not empty is that Vue encapsulate the object and make it reactive.

So when the array is populated after the execution of `created`, you see the last version of `objects`. Whereas `this.objects.slice()` is a non reactive copy of the array and `objects.length` is a primitive value and is non reactive.